# schematic design

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I have a demultiplexer and I want to design it. It is 1 in 2. It is not a multiplexer.

[image]

What I did:

[image]

*Truth table.*

```
SW1  SW2   Out1  Out2
Sel  In    LED4  LED5
---------------------
 0    0     0     0
 0    1     0     1
 1    0     0     0
 1    1     1     0
```

It is my first trial of design but I don't know if I design it right.
SW1 = Sel and SW2=In.
Out1=ln*Sel and Out2=ln*~Sel .

Comment: Connect on breadboard and find out

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a truth table of what you want. I will give you a start.

Comment: @Transistor I added the truth table.I hope that will help you

Comment: That's a little unusual. Can you add in the actual question you have been asked?

Comment: @Transistor The question was : to do a demultiplex 1 in 2.I have the equations I get from Karnaugh Out1=ln*Sel and Out2=ln*~Sel and the truth table you wanted too

Comment: That information belongs in your question, not in the comments. You also need to show which switch is 'In' and which is 'Sel'. What does '*~' mean?

Comment: SW1 = Sel and SW2=In. The ~ means the opposite,how should I symbolize it?.The * means multiple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SW1  SW2   Out1  Out2
Sel  In    LED4  LED5
---------------------
 0    0     0     0
 0    1     0     1
 1    0     0     0
 1    1     1     0

Out1 = Sel AND In.
Out2 = NOT Sel AND In.
```

[image]

*Figure 1. OP's schematic.*

You have `LED4 = NOT Sel AND In`. You have `LED5 = Sel AND in`. Your circuit is correct if LED4 is Out2 and LED5 is Out1.

Lessons:

- Supply the full question.
- Draw a truth table. It is much better than words.
- Label everything consistently. On your schematic we don't know the purpose of the switches. They are not numbered and are not labelled. We don't know which LED is Out1 and Out2.

You can simulate your circuit easily using one of the many online logic simulators such as https://logic.ly/demo.